# Tableau Fiscal Date Calculation

Tags: tableau-api

How can I get this outcome in Tableau?
I am trying to compare This Fiscal Year Vs Last Fiscal Year Revenue Data.
I need a calculation that will be able to add an extra day for order_date dimension. 
Please help! 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
dateadd('day',1,[order date])
```

Check out this link for more date calculations.
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.htm